# Not able to restrict "alt+c" combination in ie using mousetrap

Tags: jquery

I needs to restrict "alt+c" combination for IE9, IE10, IE11. I have tried out with return false, returnValue=false, stopPropagation(), preventDefault() and cancelbubble. Still i am not able to stop the default behavior of IE. I have tried with the followig code with mousetrap:

```
private _setupKeyboardShortcuts() {
    Mousetrap.stopCallback = function () {return false;
            }
            Mousetrap.bind('alt+c', (e) => {
                // Cancel      
                e.preventDefault(); 
                var event = window.event;
                if (event.preventDefault)
                    event.preventDefault();
                else 
                    event.returnValue = false;
                return false;
            });  
}
```

Comment: What does `Alt` + `C` do in IE?

Comment: When i am pressing Alt + C the code i have written in mousetrap is running, after that browser history of IE has been open. I need to restrict by not opening the browser history when i am giving Alt + C.

Comment: I am just asking how to restrict the default behavior of IE, but the solution given here is not suitable for my question. They have explained how to detect the "ALT + C" combination in IE using key press event and didn't mentioned how to overcome the actual behavior of IE.